# python 3 import module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to import a module from a different sub directory in Python 3 and I'm having trouble getting the script running. The current file structure I have is:

```
/lets_import
    __init__.py
    /app
        __init__.py
        main.py
        server.py
    /tests
        __init__.py
        tests_main.py
```

`tests_main.py` imports a function from `server.py` like this:

`from app.server import add`
(add is the function being imported from server.py)

**init** files are empty. They are there so that each sub dir is seen as a package.

When I run `tests_main.py` I get the following error

```
File "tests/tests_main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myapp.server import add
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'
```

I tried running it from the root level folder like this `python test/tests_main.py` but still got the same error.

Is there a way to do this without having to manipulate PYTHONPATH?

Comment: `myapp` or `app`?

Comment: _Is there a way to do this without having to manipulate PYTHONPATH_ Sure, just put all your modules in one directory.  But that's a terrible solution.  `PYTHONPATH` exists for a reason.

Comment: No PYTHONPATH manipulation required: `sys.path.insert(0, os.abspath('..'))`

Comment: If this is in a module, I think you can do `from ..app.server import add`, no?

Comment: @WendingPeng it's app. the error message is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon correct me if im wrong, but I believe you can't do relative imports in Python 3?

Comment: You can, I just tested it.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon hmmm, i get this error `  File "tests_main.py", line 2, in <module> from ..app.server import add SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: Look at the answers to the other question, this is a straight duplicate. They discuss that error.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon thanks